# Transforming the prediction target

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset in which each observation may belong to different labels(multi-label classification).

I have done SVM classification on it and its working. (here I was interested in seeing the accuracy per class so I applied `OneVsRestClassifier` per class as you will see in the code.)

I want to see the predicted value for each item in the test data. In another word, Id like to see which label the model has predicted per observation in the test samples.

**For example: 
this is the data passed to the model to predict**

```
,sentences,ADR,WD,EF,INF,SSI,DI,others
0,"extreme weight gain, short-term memory loss, hair loss.",1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,I am detoxing from Lexapro now.,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
2,I slowly cut my dosage over several months and took vitamin supplements to help.,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
3,I am now 10 days completely off and OMG is it rough.,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
4,"I have flu-like symptoms, dizziness, major mood swings, lots of anxiety, tiredness.",0,1,0,0,0,0,1
5,I have no idea when this will end.,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
```

then my model has predicted the labels for these rows,  I want to see the predicted mapping for each row.

I know that we can do that using `Label Binarization` in scikit-learn library.

The problem is the input argument of `fit_transform` explained [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html)  differs from the target data I have prepared and passed to SVM classification.
So I do not know how to figure it out.

This is my code :

```
df = pd.read_csv("finalupdatedothers.csv")
categories = ['ADR','WD','EF','INF','SSI','DI','others']

train,test = train_test_split(df,random_state=42,test_size=0.3,shuffle=True)
X_train = train.sentences
X_test = test.sentences

SVC_pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=1)),
            ])

for category in categories:
    print('... Processing {} '.format(category))
    SVC_pipeline.fit(X_train,train[category]
    prediction = SVC_pipeline.predict(X_test)
    print('SVM Linear Test accuracy is {} '.format(accuracy_score(test[category], prediction)))
    print 'SVM Linear f1 measurement is {} '.format(f1_score(test[category], prediction, average='weighted'))
    print "\n"
```

I appreciate your time.

Comment: did you mean to say that you want to know the designated labels from `prediction` variable?

Comment: @user2906838 thanks for the comment. I mean, if in the test data I have a row like " I hate this drug"  then my model has predicted as ADR. so I want to see this mapping for all the testing data. Am I clear?

Comment: Oh yes, Sorry though, Can you please share a sample of yoru csv just to re-produce your output. I may be able to help.

Comment: Sure thanks for helping :)

Comment: Can you please check now if that data works? but imagine that as we pass for the testing, testing data wont have the label

Comment: Oh, Ok then this is the case of `having a model`. In my case I need both, first to have a trained model and then only I would be able to run the test. I would suggest you to give a re-reproducible example

Comment: @user2906838 do you mean you need more sample data? the format is the same actually this is the way my dataframe look like you just need to copy the same if you need more data . Im not sure I got your point correctly please let me know if you meant something else. Many Thanks

Comment: to fit the model, there in the data, I need the label, one way is I can place them randomly as I want, or you could just provide. I'm asking for a producable example of your problem. Thanks

Comment: @user2906838 oh sorry I forgot to elaborate about the labels, so only the sentence is my data the whole numbers front of the sentence is my labels. Actually I have 7 labels the same as you see in the data frame. Is it the thing you were looking for?

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sentences'` when I try to run the code. Do you have labels in your csv file. I meant the column names?

Comment: Would you please have a look now? I forgot to put column name for the data frame. It only did not have column name . Thanks.

Comment: @user2906838 I have updated the data frame, is it now ok?

Comment: Yes, I'm just pasting the answer, I have re-produced it. Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks for taking the time

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: sure just a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want, what I just did, is that I mapped the `prediction` which is a numpy array representing the class labels index in your `categories` list. So here's the complete code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets import samples_generator
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_regression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
df = pd.read_csv("finalupdatedothers.csv")
categories = ['ADR','WD','EF','INF','SSI','DI','others']

train,test = train_test_split(df,random_state=42,test_size=0.3,shuffle=True)
X_train = train.sentences
X_test = test.sentences

SVC_pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=[])),
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=1)),
            ])


for category in categories:
    print('... Processing {} '.format(category))
    SVC_pipeline.fit(X_train,train[category])
    prediction = SVC_pipeline.predict(X_test)
    print([{X_test.iloc[i]:categories[prediction[i]]} for i in range(len(list(prediction)))  ])

    print('SVM Linear Test accuracy is {} '.format(accuracy_score(test[category], prediction)))
    print ('SVM Linear f1 measurement is {} '.format(f1_score(test[category], prediction, average='weighted')))
    print ("\n")
```

And here's the sample output:

```
... Processing ADR 
[{'extreme weight gain, short-term memory loss, hair loss.': 'ADR'}, {'I am detoxing from Lexapro now.': 'ADR'}]
SVM Linear Test accuracy is 0.5 
SVM Linear f1 measurement is 0.3333333333333333 


... Processing WD 
[{'extreme weight gain, short-term memory loss, hair loss.': 'ADR'}, {'I am detoxing from Lexapro now.': 'ADR'}]
SVM Linear Test accuracy is 1.0 
SVM Linear f1 measurement is 1.0
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: why am I getting weird error ! tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 114, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0L

Comment: May I know your version of pandas please?

Comment: It's `0.22.0` . You don't have a key `OL` in your data as per the error.

Comment: no 0L does not make sense in my data. I guess it related to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087247/pandas-series-cant-get-index may I know what is the type of the index in your df?

Comment: `,sentences,ADR,WD,EF,INF,SSI,DI,others` This is what I have

Comment: I mean type of the index, as the first column is the index and there is 0 1 2 ...

Comment: `,sentences,ADR,WD,EF,INF,SSI,DI,others`
`0,"extreme weight gain, short-term memory loss, hair loss.",1,0,0,0,0,0,0` This is how it is represented.

Comment: Yea so my question is that you have not changed or delete the first column here means 0?  sorry for taking your time

Comment: Ok I changed the `X_test[i]` to `X_test.iloc[i]`. Should work can you please check?

Comment: well seems one row in my data has problem because it printing some and then raises this error TypeError: list indices must be integers, not numpy.string_

Comment: Probably, this should work, if you have everything as you provided in your question. I meant mostly the data, because it works fine for me. Ofcourse in this sample data. Do you want me to update the answer with the data that I've been using?

Comment: thank you so much. yea I believe it should work. only one thing is there anyway here to say only consider int indices? because it complaining of string indices?

Comment: Well, yes, but in which line?

Comment: Actually, It's on the line we added for printing the result. actually without that with the same dataset is working when I added that line this raises

Comment: `[categories[i] for i in list(prediction)]` This gives you the predicted categoires, the other one is just to map the sentence and create a dict. You could have that without using list comprehension as well. In that way you could be able to debug it.